# how to fix error NativeAnimatedModule & startAnimatingNode on react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

Error:

```
Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"75325":{"module":"NativeAnimatedModule","method":"startAnimatingNode"},
```

Code

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const ProductView = ({ navigation }) => {

    const apiData = useSelector((state) => state.ApiData.data)
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const t = setInterval(
            () => setProduct(apiData),
            200,
        );
        return () => clearInterval(t);
    }, []);
    const route = useRoute()
    ///-------------------------
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
    const id = route.params?.id;
    const item = product.find((i) => i.id === id)



    useEffect(() => {
        if (item) {
            setCurrentIndex(product.indexOf(item));
        }
    }, [item, id]);

    const handleScroll = (event) => {
        const contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
        const index = Math.round(contentOffset / SCREEN_WIDTH);
        setCurrentIndex(index);
    };
    //-------------------product_division---------------------------->



    // <-----------------------------------horizontal screen--------------------------------------------->
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.body} key={item.id}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.container} >
                    <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: item.image ? item.image : null }} style={styles.productImg} resizeMode='contain' />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 15, justifyContent: 'space-between', }}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>

                                <Text style={styles.textItem}>Brand name</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.title}>{item?.title}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', }}>
                               

                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.fontStyle}>Composition</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Composition</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.box}>
                            <Text style={styles.fontStyle}>Packing</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textParagraph}>Packing</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.textPrice}>Rs 21</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.fontStyle}>Segment</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Segment</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.box}>
                            <Text style={styles.fontStyle}>Mktd. By</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textParagraph}>Mktd. By</Text>
                        </View>

                            
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', borderStyle: 'dashed', borderColor: '#7ABF49', borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 10, paddingBottom: 10, marginTop: 12, marginBottom: 5 }}>
                                <Text style={[styles.fontStyle, { paddingStart: 10, color: '#7ABF49' }]}>Special offer</Text>
                                {/* {availableOffer ? <Text style={[styles.title, { paddingStart: 10 }]}></Text> : <Text style={[styles.title, { paddingStart: 10 }]}>No offer available </Text>} */}


                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>


            </ScrollView>
        </View>

    );

    return (


        <LinearGradient
            colors={['#7ABF49', '#13A15D']}
            start={{ x: 0.99, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
            style={styles.linearGradient}
        >
            <HeaderItem navigation={navigation} />

            <FlatList
                data={product}
                horizontal={true}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={handleScroll}
                scrollEventThrottle={25}
                contentOffset={{
                    x: currentIndex * SCREEN_WIDTH,
                    y: 0,
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />


        </LinearGradient>

    )
}
```